# Color set by textMateRules is ignored but fontStyle is respected in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I would like to highlight the function definition arguments / area in c++.
In the picture below **(A)**, you can see how the function definition area `setAge(int age)` looks like by default. By adding the following `textMateRules` into my `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` file

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "punctuation.section.parameters.end.bracket.round.cpp,punctuation.section.parameters.begin.bracket.round.cpp",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000",
                    "fontStyle": "bold",
                }
            },
            {
                "scope": "meta.parameter.cpp",
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ff0000",
                    "fontStyle": "bold",
                }
            },
        ]
    }
```

I achieve that `setAge(int age)` is bold, however you can also see that the foreground color statement is just ignored (`setAge(int age)` is not red)!

[image]

I really don't understand why the foreground color argument is ignored when using "meta.parameter.cpp" and "punctuation.section.parameters.end.bracket.round.cpp,punctuation.section.parameters.begin.bracket.round.cpp"

Any idea?

PS:

I know that the statement works in general, because I can e.g. color all variables passed to a function by adding:

```
{
    "scope": "variable.parameter.cpp",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#ff0000",
            "fontStyle": "bold",
        }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this setting is overriden in the inner scope *variable.parameter.cpp*:

[image]

Comment: And how can I fix this or do you have an idea where it gets overriden? It is an unexpected behvaiour for me, as I would expect the more specific rule to overpower the more generic one.

Comment: Regarding specificity of the rules please check [Ranking Matches](https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors#ranking-matches). Looks like `variable.parameter.cpp` is more specific than `meta.parameter.cpp`. I think you can write your own rule for `variable.parameter.cpp` to override the setting.